# How to write linq to join two tables with no relationship?

Tags: linq-to-entities

Suppose I have two tables:

```
Tab1(id, shareid, ....)
Tab2(id, shareid, ...)
```

DB was modeled by EF. 
Then I want to a linq get same result as following sql:

```
select t1.* from Tab1 t1 join Tab2 t2 on t1.shareid=t2.shareID
```

So linq should be somthing like:

```
ObjectContext.Tab1s.Where(...);
```

How to write the linq for this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will be something that looks like this:

```
var Result = (from t1 in TBL1
               join t2 in TBL2 on t1.SharedId equals t2.SharedId
               where t1.whatever == t2.whatever
               select new{bla,bla,bla,bla} );
```

Comment: With this kind of linq, how to add Include("Tab3") for eager loading?